# How to refresh event argument on mouse down with interval?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Since `onmousedown` doesn't work like if you were to hold `onkeydown` I have had to compromise and create my own style of it, so far I have come up with this:

```
can.onmousedown = function(e) { 
    map.moving = setInterval(function() {
        console.log(e.pageX + ' ' + e.pageY);
        map.posX = e.pageX;
        map.posY = e.pageY;
    }, 70);
}

can.onmouseup = function(e) {
    clearInterval(map.moving);
}
```

Which works great, the only problem I'm having now, is that the `e` argument is only being set upon initial click so the mouse coords stay the same for the entire interval, any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Start with `mousedown`, drag with `mousemove`, stop with `mouseup`

Comment: Just an example of jAndys answer: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4uaa/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke `mousemove` aswell.

```
can.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if( map.moving ) {
        console.log(e.pageX + ' ' + e.pageY);
        map.posX = e.pageX;
        map.posY = e.pageY;
    }
};

can.onmousedown = function(e) {
    map.moving = true;
};

can.onmouseup = function(e) {
    map.moving = false;
};
```

Optionally, you probably want to decouple and slow down the execution of `mousemove` handlers, since that happens (like the `scroll events`, very fast). That could be done also invoking `timeouts` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
can.onmousedown = function(e) { 
    map.moving = setInterval(function() {
        e = e || window.event;
        console.log(e.pageX + ' ' + e.pageY);
        map.posX = e.pageX;
        map.posY = e.pageY;
    }, 70);
}

can.onmouseup = function(e) {
    clearInterval(map.moving);
}
```